# Using RegEx to find a specific word even if it has been separated by nonLetter characters

Tags: regex

Regex may not be the correct tool for this, so if that is the case that is a good answer as well.

I'd like to find a word even if its been split by non Letter characters.  For example if i'm trying to find `One`, `O-ne` would match, `--O__n--e` would match but `O--nce` would not.

To avoid the XY problem: This is for matching words in a profanity filter. This case came up and there is a fairly straightforward (if long) solution using `String.toLower`, `String.Indexof` and `String.Replace` to remove all the non letters, replace the word with `*`s and then reconstruct the original string.  I was trying to find a solution using regular expressions.  Here is what I've tried so far:

```
(.\*)(([^a-zA-Z]*)(?i)(Y)([^a-zA-Z]*)(?i)(e)([^a-zA-Z]*)(?i)(s)([^a-zA-Z]*)\b)(.\*)
```

It matches something like `I wasn't born --Y_e--s`, but not `I wasn't born --Y_e--st`.

So I added a `?` after the `\b` to make the `--Y_e--s` portion optional (of course the beginning (`.*`) greedily matches the entire string no matter what everytime), changing it to this:

```
(.\*?)(([^a-zA-Z]*)(?i)(Y)([^a-zA-Z]*)(?i)(e)([^a-zA-Z]*)(?i)(s)([^a-zA-Z]*)\b)?(.\*?)
```

which doesn't match anything.

I'm stumped.  What I'd like is this:

```
(Capture Group start of string) (Capture group of my Target word that might be separated by non Letter characters) (Capture Group of End of string).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not sure which regex flavour you use but you can try this.

https://regex101.com/r/qR1aP5/1

```
(\S)\s*(\S+)(\S)\s*(\S+)(\S)\s*(\S+)
```

Match against this text

```
I wasn't born --Y_e--s
```